# Confusion regarding a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-theorem

I tried much but was unable to find the answer.
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1 \cdot 3}{3\cdot 6} + \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{3\cdot 6\cdot 9} + \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7}{3\cdot 6\cdot 9\cdot 12} \ldots \infty$$

We have to find value of $X$. I think its an expansion of something, but don't know which.
Thank you. 
By the way,the Answer is $2$.

Comment: What is $X$ meant to represent?

Comment: A good start might be to write the general term as $\displaystyle \frac{(2n)!/n!2^n}{n!3^n} = \binom{2n}n (1/6)^n$

Comment: By the way, the answer should be $\sqrt{3} - 1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may recall the following result, coming from the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalisations):
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}n x^n=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}},\quad |x|<1/4.
$$ then take into account @Henning Makholm's comment.

Comment: @Norsky Yo are welcome. Thanks!